# VBA move row data to their related sheet but if duplicate row found then skip that row

Tags: vba

I have a sheet named **"RAW ITEMS"** with data, and also have few more sheets with different name, where i need to move data from **"RAW ITEMS"** sheet. and all sheet name are available at sheet **"RAW ITEMS"** in Column C3 to C100.
When I run below code It's works good when I run it first time.
But when I add some data to Sheet "RAW ITEMS", It's also move earlier Rows to their related sheet. I can't figure out how to stop moving duplicate rows.
I mean **how to skip if duplicate raw found in those sheets where data are moving?**

```
Sub copyPasteData()

Dim PV As String
Dim ps As String
Dim LastRow As Long

PV = "RAW ITEMS"

Sheets(PV).Visible = True
Sheets(PV).Select

Range("C3").Select

Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    ps = ActiveCell.Value
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count).Select
    Selection.Copy
    
    Sheets(ps).Visible = True
    Sheets(ps).Select
    LastRow = pvs("A")
    Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets(PV).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
    Range("A1").Select
    
End Sub

Public Function pvs(col)
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    pvs = LastRow
End Function
```

I am newbies in VBA. Please help me.

how to skip if duplicate raw found in those sheets where data are moving?

[This is the file link for better understand](https://mega.nz/file/E882HZ6A#G_UUNyJKD5vkvRDsGsOy_Vm0wZJOibjgmAfdjtwFYHs)

Comment: You should watch; [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) to learn how to work with ranges.

Comment: It would help to have sample data. The best approach will be different depending on whether the data has unique idea or not. If the Raw Item data will never be sorted, you could keep a record of the last row that was processed and start the loop after that row.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please. It avoids any selection, activation which consumes Excel resources, without bringing any benefit. It should be fast, using arrays and working in memory:

```
Sub copyPasteData()
 Dim PVWs As Worksheet, PSWs As Worksheet, arrPV, arrPS, arPV, arPS
 Dim LastRPv  As Long, LastRPs As Long, lastCol As Long, i As Long
 Dim j As Long, boolCopy As Boolean

 Set PVWs = Worksheets("RAW ITEMS")
 LastRPv = PVWs.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 lastCol = PVWs.UsedRange.Columns.Count

 'load the range in an array:
 arrPV = PVWs.Range(PVWs.Range("A" & 2), PVWs.Cells(LastRPv, lastCol)).Value

 For i = 1 To UBound(arrPV) 'iterate between the array rows
    On Error Resume Next
     Set PSWs = Worksheets(CStr(arrPV(i, 3)))    'set the sheet to paste, if no a similar row exists
     If Err.Number = 9 Then
        Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
        Dim ans As VbMsgBoxResult
        ans = MsgBox("The sheet " & CStr(arrPV(i, 3)) & " does  not exist!" & vbCrLf & _
                     "Would you like to create it?", vbYesNo, "Sheet creation confirmation")
            If ans <> vbYes Then GoTo OverIt
            Set PSWs = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)) 'add the new sheet (after the last)
            PSWs.Name = arrPV(i, 3) 'name the newly inserted sheet
            'copy the header from the previous sheet:
            PSWs.Previous.Range("A1:G1").Copy Destination:=PSWs.Range("A1")
     End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    arPV = Application.Index(arrPV, i, 0) 'a slice of the i row (1D array)
    
    LastRPs = PSWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row
    'load the sheet existing range in an array
    arrPS = PSWs.Range(PSWs.Range("A" & 1), PSWs.Cells(LastRPs, lastCol)).Value
    For j = 1 To UBound(arrPS) ' iterate and check if the sliced rows are all the elements identic
        boolCopy = True
        arPS = Application.Index(arrPS, j, 0) 'a slice of the j row (1D array)
        If Join(arPV, "|") = Join(arPS, "|") Then 'check if the rows are the same
            boolCopy = False: Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If boolCopy Then
        'if not alsready in the sheet, the array is copied
        PSWs.Range("A" & LastRPs + 1).Resize(1, UBound(arPV)).Value = arPV
        boolCopy = False 'reinitialize the Boolean variable
    End If
OverIt:
 Next i
End Sub
```

The code logic assumes that "**duplicate row**" means that all the cells values on a sheet to copy row are identic whit the one of the analyzed row to be copied.

And in the C column the sheet itself name should exist...

Comment: @Prabhat Vishwas: Did you find some time to test the above code?

Comment: Dear Mr. FaneDuru, Thanks for your kind reply. for your better understand i am uploading the file for you. [link] (https://mega.nz/file/E882HZ6A#G_UUNyJKD5vkvRDsGsOy_Vm0wZJOibjgmAfdjtwFYHs).

Comment: @Prabhat Vishwas: I could not imagine that you will name the sheets 1, 2, 3... In VBA `Worksheet(1)` means **first sheet** and `Worksheet("1")` means **sheet having the name "1"**. I will adapt the code to make a string conversion. Besides that, I think it is good to let the code check if the sheet name of C column exists and if not, to ask about creation it. If you press "Yes" it will be added after the last one. If not, this row will be skipped. You maybe only misspelled the name and will corect it after the code run.

Comment: Adapted the above code. [Here](https://easyupload.io/0kli73) is the adapted workbook. We here, if somebody spends some time and solve our question, vote the answer up and most important, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue, will know that the code works...

Comment: Unbelievable, Really you have a god level talent. Thanks Mr. FaneDuru, Hats Off.

Comment: @Prabhat Vishwas: Glad I could help! Now, it will be good for you to try understanding the code. Our main purpose here is learning (and teaching, if possible)...